# How to send mail from Databricks notebook using AWS SES in python (Without using access key id and secret access key)

Tags: python, boto3, databricks, amazon-iam, amazon-ses

My task is to create a method that sends mail to recipients with attachment , i used aws access key id and secret key to access ses and sent mail using send_raw_email method. It is working fine. But they dont want me to use keys instead they ask me to create IAM role with proper permission to access ses.I am not sure how to create IAM role with policy to access ses and how to implement the same in code.
Also i could not find 'IAM role' option under 'Advanced options' in databricks cluster configuration for IAM role assignment.Kindly pour your suggestions.

Using keys:

client = boto3.client(
'ses',
region_name="us-east-2",
aws_access_key_id='',
aws_secret_access_key=''
)